# Which URL we should use for KinesisVideoStream KVS GetMedia and GetDataEndpoint API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis

I went through AWS docs and found that for to fetch straming media from Kinesis we must use KVS GetMedia API and before that we need to get endpoint URL using GetDataEndpoint API

Can any one tell which URL I should use to send request ?

```
POST /getDataEndpoint HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json

{
   "APIName": "string",
   "StreamARN": "string",
   "StreamName": "string"
}


POST /getMedia HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json

{
   "StartSelector": { 
      "AfterFragmentNumber": "string",
      "ContinuationToken": "string",
      "StartSelectorType": "string",
      "StartTimestamp": number
   },
   "StreamARN": "string",
   "StreamName": "string"
}
```

Comment: same question, were you able to figure it out ?

Comment: @Sujith Sizon use boto3 just like mentioned in my below question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228502/how-to-decode-aws-kinesis-video-stream-getmedia-api-output-to-mp3-wav?noredirect=1#comment100243167_55228502